# How to select a specific tag content inside li tag?

Tags: jquery, select, tags

```
<ul id="listQ">
   <li><txt>part01</txt><from>part02</from></li>
   <li><txt>part01</txt><from>part02</from></li>
</ul>

$(document).ready(function() {
  var list = $('#listQ li');
  $('#tv').html($(list).eq(0).text());
});
```

So, this will place "part01part02" inside #tv.
How can I get just `txt` content inside #tv (part01 in this case) ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this [JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/R5chY/)

```
$('#tv').html($("#listQ li:first txt").text());
```